# How to simplify macro declaration?

Tags: keyboard-macros

Using `kmacro-exec-ring-item`, is it possible to wrap this in an elisp macro or function so its much less verbose?

In this example the only unique part is `ds(` and the function name.

```
(fset
 'delete-surround-parens
 (lambda (&optional arg) "" (interactive "p")
   (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([?d ?s ?( ] 0 %d)) arg)))
```

Could this be wrapped so it could be written as something more simple, for eg:

```
(fset 'delete-surround-parens (my-kmacro-wrapper "ds("))
```

I'm not sure how to convert the literal string into an array to pass to `kmacro-exec-ring-item`, but interested to know if its possible.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you want to make it less verbose? What is the problem you are trying to solve? disk space? memory? debugging ease? This sounds, so far, like it might be an [X Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding own answer since this cam be written as a macro:

```
(defmacro kmacro-fn (keys)
  `(lambda (&optional arg) "" (interactive "p")
     (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote (,keys 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

Example use:

```
(fset 'delete-surround-backtick     (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?`]))
(fset 'delete-surround-single_quote (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?']))
(fset 'delete-surround-double_quote (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?\"]))
(fset 'delete-surround-paren        (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?(]))
(fset 'delete-surround-bracket      (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?[]))
(fset 'delete-surround-brace        (kmacro-fn [?d ?s ?{]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;; Keyboard Macro
(fset 'delete-surround-parens "ds(")

;; or normal Function
(defun delete-surround-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (command-execute "ds("))
```

`ds(` here is valid Emacs key representation, for complex keys, wrap that with `kbd`, for example,

```
(fset 'next-4-lines (kbd "C-u M-x next-line RET"))
```